# Dapper can't find POCO mapping from SELECT CASE query

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I'm extracting information from a SQL Server database using Dapper. The POCO for the information in question is below.

```
public class Client
    {
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        public string ContactDetail { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string District { get; set; }
        public string Town { get; set; }
        public string County { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
    }
```

When I extract the information for the above object using the query below all the information is mapped correctly, apart from the following line `max(case when cd.Type = 1 OR cd.Type = 2 then cd.Detail end) as 'ContactDetail'` I believe this may be because I am not simply extracting the data from a table column and I am instead doing some processing using the CASE clause beforehand and therefore Dapper cannot find the correct place to map the information onto.

I thought including the `AS` clause would help Dapper to find the correct mapping but this didn't actually work.

How can I change my query so that Dapper can map the ContactDetail data correctly?

```
select 
tp.ShortName as 'ShortName', 
max(case when cd.Type = 1 OR cd.Type = 2 then cd.Detail end) as 'ContactDetail',
tp.Street, 
tp.District, 
tp.Town, 
tp.County, 
tp.PostCode
... (rest of query snipped as unneeded)
```

I know the query works correctly as I can run it in SSMS and it returns the correct information.

Answer (score 1):

Dapper doesn't have any interest or knowledge of what is inside the query - it *only* cares about the shape of the results. So: whatever is happening - it is part of the query.

My hunches would be:

- the data genuinely is missing and/or `null`
- something to do with `null` handling and null-coalescing, perhaps with the `max` complicating things

Note that you can't *just* compare to SSMS output, because SSMS and ADO.NET (`SqlClient`) can have different `SET` option defaults, which can make significant yet subtle differences to some queries.

To investigate it *properly*, I'd really need a reproducible example (presumably with fake data); without that, we're kinda guessing.

To reiterate, though:

I strongly suspect that if you execute the same query via `ExecuteReader` or similar, you'll find that the value coming back in that position is indeed `null` (or `DBNull`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the issue is that if you're using the object mapper in Dapper (i.e. Client in <>) then it will simply look for those columns in the matching table.  The "ContactDetail" does not exist (it's derived), so it will not find it.

You have a couple of options here, depending on your data and use case.

- Get the raw data from Dapper, and then use Linq (or similar) to derive the ContactDetail using logic within the program.
- Write a stored procedure based on your query, and use Dapper to run it
- Use Dapper's Query command to run your SQL statement, instead of trying to directly map the object.

Let me know if you get stuck on this, or require further explanation.